# AngularJS: error when calling service function from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The error I'm going to describe here seems to be very common; I've read many pages on the web (comprised some posts on this forum), but I haven't found any solution, maybe due to the fact that I'm new to AngularJS.

I designed a service which has a function whose sole role is retrieving a resource and returning it:

```
myApp.service('htmlGettersService', function ($http, $sce, $q) {
    this.getHtmlIsa = function (codice_isa) {
        return {
            console.log("Get HTML Isa...");

            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/' + appName + '/api/quadri/' + codice_isa,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'
                }
            };

            var htmlQuadri = {};
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http(req).then(function (response) {
                htmlQuadri = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
                console.log("HTML Isa acquisito correttamente");
            }, function (response) {
                console.log("Errore in Get HTML Isa..." + response.message);
                htmlQuadri = ("Errore in Get HTML Isa..." + response.message).promise;
            });

            deferred.resolve(htmlQuadri);

            console.log("Exit from service function");
            //          return htmlQuadri;
            return deferred.promise;

        };

    }
});
```

In this context, I had to insert a deferring tactic, since the service function seems to terminate before the GET call (and the success/failure function) have finished their work.
Secondly, I tried to call service function from controller:

```
 $scope.getHtmlIsa = function () {

    htmlGettersService.getHtmlIsa($scope.codice_isa).then(function (response) {
        $scope.htmlQuadri = response.data;
    });

    console.log("Controller: exit from getHtmlIsa");
}
```

At the end, I get the following error:

```
angular.js:14525 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.getHtmlIsa (quadriController.js:51)
    at Object.<anonymous> (quadriController.js:120)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:10866)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9746)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9055)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8920)
    at Object.link (angular-route.js:1223)
    at angular.js:1346
    at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:10426) "<ng-view class="ng-scope">"
```

I tried to use the same deferring tactic insiede controller, too; the error reported above disappeared, but it seems that controller function terminates before the service function has returned anything, so there's not enough time to save response from service inside controller variable.
Any clue? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: your code is unreadable, sorry

Answer (score 0):

`this.getHtmlIsa` should return Promise in order to resolve it in controller (a.e. `.then()`)

However in your case you return object that returns Promise with also wrong syntax:

```
 return {
  //...       
  return deferred.promise;
  }
```

For sure its not what you want to do

---

Also its not good practice to use `deferred`. Please read this [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

So the right syntax should be something like:

```
myApp.service('htmlGettersService', function($http, $sce, $q) 
{
    this.getHtmlIsa = function(codice_isa)
    {
            console.log("Get HTML Isa...");

            var req = 
            {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/'+appName+'/api/quadri/' + codice_isa,
                    headers: 
                    {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'
                    }
            };

            var htmlQuadri = {};           

            return $http(req).then(function(response){
                htmlQuadri = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
                console.log("HTML Isa acquisito correttamente");
                return htmlQuadri;
            }, function(response){
                console.log("Errore in Get HTML Isa..."+response.message);
                htmlQuadri = ("Errore in Get HTML Isa..."+response.message).promise;
                 return htmlQuadri;
            });           
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I read many posts about the use of external return: some use it, some don't. at the beginning I hadn't used it, then I added it, since I saw it many times.
since I'm new to AngularJS, I've many doubts about syntax. Could you tell me explicitly where I mistook?

Comment: @Bia I think you mix with syntax of `factory` :)  here we talk about `service` method

Comment: sorry for this messy post, I've been given a task at work and I have not time to learn this subject properly (books, example, tutorials, exercises).
I will use your suggestions and let you know